# How to create 2dsphere index in motor .

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado-motor

I try to write geospatial queries.
I use motor for connection to MongoDB.This how I  insert data.

```
result = yield db['users'].find_and_modify(query={"email": data['email'], "password": data['password']},
                                               update={"$set": {
                                                   "location": {"coordinates": {"longitude": data['longitude'],
                                                                                "latitude": data['latitude']}}}},
                                               upsert=True)
```

But I can`t create index for this field.
I try :

```
 yield db.users.create_index({"location": "2dsphere"})
```

But I have error

> TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
>   ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET

Comment: Will you accept my answer as correct, or is there something else I can help you with?

Answer (score 2):

Same as PyMongo, plus a "yield":

```
yield db.users.create_index([("location", "2dsphere")])
```

The Python drivers for MongoDB require a list of tuples, not a dict, when creating an index, because key order matters and dicts don't preserve key order.